# Trying to use PHP and Ajax to do form validation, not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, validation

I have been trying to figure out how to do php form validation and using ajax to get the results back so I don't have to refresh page. I'm new to ajax and having a hard time.
This is my registration.php form

```
<h1>Sign Up</h1>
<form id="registration_form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="first_name">First name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name" name="first_name" onblur="validate('first_name', this.value)" placeholder="First name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="textFirstName" class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name" name="last_name" onblur="validate('last_name', this.value)" placeholder="Last name">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="textLastName" class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email1" name="email1" onblur="validate('email1', this.value)" placeholder="Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="textEmail" class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" name="password1" onblur="validate('password1', this.value)" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="textPass1" class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Password2">Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" name="password2" onblur="validate('password2', this.value)" placeholder="Retype Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="textPass2" class="col-md-6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my validation php script:

```
 <?php
$value = $_POST['query'];
$formfield = $_POST['field'];
// Check Valid or Invalid first name when user enters user name in username     input field.
if ($formfield == "first_name") {
    if (strlen($value) < 1) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Must be 1+ letters</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p style=\"color:green\">Valid</p>";
        $_SESSION['reg']['first_name'] = $value;
    }
}
if ($formfield == "last_name") {
    if (strlen($value) < 1) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Must be 1+ letters</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p style=\"color:green\">Valid</p>";
        $_SESSION['reg']['last_name'] = $value;
    }
}
// Check Valid or Invalid password when user enters password in password input field.
if ($formfield == "password1") {
    if (strlen($value) < 8) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Password too short. Must be at least 8 characters long, contain one lower case letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.</p>";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("#.*^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$#", $value)){
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Your password must be at least 8 characters long, contain one lower case letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p style=\"color:green\">Your password is good.</p>";
        $_SESSION['reg']['password1'] = $value;
    }
 }
 if ($formfield == "password2") {
    if (strlen($value) < 8) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Password too short. Must be at least 8 characters long, contain one lower case letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.</p>";
    }
    else if (!preg_match("#.*^(?=.{8,20})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).*$#", $value)){
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Your password must be at least 8 characters long, contain one lower case letter, one uppercase letter, and one number.</p>";
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['password1'] != $value) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Error: Your passwords don't match.</p>";
    }
    else {
        echo "<p style=\"color:green\">Your password is good.</p>";
    }
}
// Check Valid or Invalid email when user enters email in email input field.
if ($formfield == "email1") {
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $value)) {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Invalid email.</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p style=\"color:red\">Valid</p>";
        $_SESSION['reg']['email1'] = $value;
    }
}

?>
```

And this is my javascript file with the ajax:

```js
function checkForm() {
// Fetching values from all input fields and storing them in variables.
var first_name = document.getElementById("first_name").value;
var last_name = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
var password1 = document.getElementById("password1").value;
var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
//Check input Fields Should not be blanks.
if (first_name == '' || last_name == '' || password1 == '' || password2 == '' || email1 == '') {
alert("Fill All Fields");
} else {
//Notifying error fields
var textFirstName = document.getElementById("first_name");
var textLastName = document.getElementById("last_name");
var textPass1 = document.getElementById("password1");
var textPass2 = document.getElementById("password2");
var textEmail = document.getElementById("email1");
//Check All Values/Informations Filled by User are Valid Or Not.If All Fields Are invalid Then Generate alert.
str1 = textFirstName.innerHTML; str2 = textLastName.innerHTML; str3 = textPass1.innerHTML; str4 = textPass2.innerHTML; str5 = textEmail.innerHTML;
if (str1.substr(0,4) == 'Error' || str2.substr(0,4) == 'Error' || str3.substr(0,4) == 'Error' || str4.substr(0,4) == 'Error' || str5.substr(0,4) == 'Error') {
alert("Fill Valid Information");
} else {
//Submit Form When All values are valid.
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
}
}
}
// AJAX code to check input field values when onblur event triggerd.
function validate(field, query) {
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
} else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
} else {
document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a href='index.php'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
}
}
xmlhttp.open("POST", "lib/validate_registration_form.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

When I enter values in the form there is no response regardless of whether i input valid or invalid information. I am sure the problem lies in the JS file with the ajax, but I don't know what it is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your example we dont see when is called or binded the call of `validate()` ... you AJAX is never called ?

Comment: I forgot to add the onblurs to the fields. I'll do that now and if it still doesn't work I'll reupload the form

Comment: I updated the form to add the onblur events to each of the form fields, but it had no affect. The validation still doesn't happen

Answer (score 0):

You have two issue :

First, in your html/javascript the `onblur` event calls

```
validate('first_name', this.value)
```

But there is not HTML element with ID = `first_name`, your div is called `textFirstName`

So you should change your `onblur` with proper parameter value such as

```
validate('textFirstName', this.value)
```

Next, you use `POST` method for your ajax but send your parameter in the URL which are stored in the `$_GET` array

Change :

```
<?php
$value = $_POST['query'];
$formfield = $_POST['field'];
```

To :

```
<?php
$value = $_GET['query'];
$formfield = $_GET['field'];
```

Final note : you may want to use `isset($_GET['query'])` in your php script to avoid notice message of `undefined` or at least a way to debug :

```
if (!isset($_GET['query']))
{
    die ("missing parameter, report to admin that he should debug the JS");
}
```

EDIT
Following your comment, here is how to send POST data

```
var params = "field=" + field + "&query=" + query;
xmlhttp.open("POST", "lib/validate_registration_form.php", false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! One thing. I really want to send stuff by POST, because the password gets validated and I'd rather that not be part of a url. At the end of the JS script I have a line "xmlhttp.open("POST", "lib/validate_registration_form.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);"

Comment: I don't know how to edit comments, but above I hit return before i was finished. That line, i thought, makes it send things via POST. How do I change things to be sure the values are sent by POST?

Comment: when I changed my js form to do the POST as you've shown, I got errors in the console: Refused to set unsafe header "Content-length"

Comment: Then remove the line with "content-length", it seems the new RFC about AJAX do that header for you anyway. Try and see if it works (I edited the example)